# Filter a pandas Dataframe based on specific month values and conditional on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a large dataframe with the following heads

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.Dataframe(columns=['month', 'Family_id', 'house_value'])
```

Months go from 0 to 239, Family_ids up to 10900 and house values vary. So the dataframe has more than 2 and a half million lines.

I want to filter the Dataframe only for those in which there is a difference between the final house price and its initial for each family.

Some sample data would look like this:

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'month': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 239, 239], 'family_id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'house_value': [10, 10, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 10, 11]})
```

And from that sample, the resulting dataframe would be:

```
g = pd.DataFrame({'month': [0, 1, 239], 'family_id': [1, 1, 1], 'house_value': [10, 11, 11]})
```

So I thought in a code that would be something like this:

```
ft = f[f.loc['month'==239, 'house_value'] > f.loc['month'==0, 'house_value']]
```

Also tried this:

```
g = f[f.house_value[f.month==239] > f.house_value[f.month==0] and f.family_id[f.month==239] == f.family_id[f.month==0]]
```

And the above code gives an error `Keyerror: False` and `ValueError` Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: `'month'==239` You are comparing strings and this will lead to `False` and you are searching `False` in the index with the help of `.loc`. So it leads to key error. What exactly is  that you need to accomplish. Can you post the data

Comment: Both the series might have different length so you cant compare that way. So post the desired output with sample data as input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby.filter`:

```
(f.sort_values('month')
  .groupby('family_id')
  .filter(lambda g: g.house_value.iat[-1] != g.house_value.iat[0]))

#  family_id    house_value   month
#1         1             10       0
#6         1             11       1
#8         1             11     239
```

---

As commented by @Bharath, your approach errors out because for boolean filter, it expects the boolean series to have the same length as the original data frame, which is not true in both of your cases due to the filter process you applied before the comparison.

Comment: It's a fast alternative to `iloc` for getting an element from a Series object. `iat[0]` get the first element in the Series while `iat[-1]` get the last element.

Comment: @Psidom you can add my comment in you answer to say why OP's method didn't work

Comment: @Bharathshetty Added.

Comment: I voted and the key error is because of string comparision it should be `f[f.loc[f['month']==239, 'house_value']` to be valid .